# Oauth2 plain text credentials in POST request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

So I am trying out Spring Security using OAuth2 in Spring Boot 2.

I based this site as my reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/secure-spring-rest-with-spring-security-and-oauth2

Once the Authorization server has been set up, tokens can be obtained from it using   http://localhost:8080/oauth/token endpoint by passing a POST request.

What makes me squeamish is that the POST request must have my username and password as plain text

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

password
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

admin
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

password
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Isn't this a very big security threat?
Wont every router along the way from the client to server be able to see the content of the POST body?

Now to solve this suppose I use a client side symmetric encryption algorithm in javascript to encrypt the password. Since all clients will get the same encryption algorithm, the routers along the way can symmetrically decode my password. Which is not good enough.

If I had to pass the credentails as plain text, then what is the use of Spring Security?
Am I doing anything wrong here? There is no way big corporations use this.
Is there any additional facility in Spring Security that allows us to prevent this situation?

Comment: All communications between client, resource servers and authorisation server should be encrypted using an SSL certificate, that isn't for Spring Security to manage. Spring Security works at the application layer not at the HTTP transport layer.

Comment: @chirdeep , Thank you for the interest you showed. But Spring security Oauth2 works using HTTP and not HTTPS, so that caused a road block when thinking of that kind of implementation.

Comment: @SamwellTarly: To make a Spring Security OAuth2 authorization server secured, you have to change the server configuration. For example embedded Tomcat's configuration in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use HTTPS ([TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)), see [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)

> **Token Endpoint**
>
> [...]
> Since requests to the token endpoint result in the transmission of
> clear-text credentials (in the HTTP request and response), the
> authorization server MUST require the use of TLS as described in
> Section 1.6 when sending requests to the token endpoint.

If your authorization server implementation allows unsecured communication, it is not compliant to OAuth2 spec.